# how to play slider automatically

Tags: jquery, slider

I want to play this slider automatically

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/12/31/how-to-create-a-simple-multi-item-slider/

I made these updates,

```
$(function() {
        $( '#mi-slider' ).catslider();
         });
counter=1;
$( '#mi-slider' ).catslider().current=0;
setInterval(repeate,3000);
function repeate(){
        $( '#mi-slider' ).catslider().showCategory( counter );
        counter++
        if(counter>3)
        counter=0;
        }
```

but there are some problems with add and remove css classes.

Thanks.

Comment: Please post a concrete question. Which are your problems?

Comment: you can download the slider from the link, and add updated code to see the result.

Answer (score 0):

```
var changeTime = 5000;
var actualCat = 0
setInterval(function() {
self.showCategory(actualCat);
if(actualCat < $('#mi-slider ul').length - 1) {
actualCat++;
}else {
actualCat = 0;
}
}, changeTime);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try These Code

$(function() {

```
            counter=1;
            $( '#mi-slider' ).catslider().current=0;
            setInterval(repeat,3000);
            function repeat(){
                    $( '#mi-slider' ).catslider().showCategory( counter );
                    counter++
                    if(counter>3)
                    counter=0;
                    }

                });
```